# Settting a useSate value as an imported image

Tags: reactjs, image, variables, react-hooks

I want to display an imported image in Reactjs as a [src?] for a  and made a function that will set said image if a counter is equal to a number like 0 for exemple. But the image doesn't seem to get transfered correctly to the desired variable.

Here is the code I used to display the image with the counter:
(the "quiche" is the name of said imported image by the way)

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    const [image , setImage] = useState();
    
    
    const changeImage = () => {
        if (counter = donnees[0]) {
            setImage(quiche);
        }
    };
```

and here is how I am trying to display it in the React HTML part:

```
<div className="Recette-image">
                    
                    <img className="quiche" src={image}></img>


                </div>
```

I tried setting the image variable of the useState using its own setter in no avail and also tried to to use an image = ImportedImage but nothing seems to make it want to turn into said image and i'm not sure if the error is in the counter not being equal to the value I believe it is or simply that its not possible to set an image into a usestate variable

Comment: Have you imported `quiche` with the right path, tried console logging it?

Comment: Did you mean `===`?

Comment: yes sorry i meant === and no i did not try console logging quiche but i did try to send a message on the console and it says that "too many renders" have been done

Comment: Also the error shows the render going over and over 24 times and then crashes